# Ruby: Safe-navigation operator, undefined method `call`

Tags: ruby, safe-navigation-operator

I am trying to compare a number literal with the return value of a function that could return `nil` or a numeric. Consider this:

```
def unreliable
  [nil, 42].sample  
end

unreliable > 10
```

This will blow up 50% of the time with `NoMethodError: undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass`. So I tried this:

```
unreliable&.(:>, 10)
```

That approach does the `nil` guarding I expect, but I get this when `unreliable` returns `42`:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for 42:Fixnum
```

I suspect this has to do with the quirks of allowing only one instance to exist for each `Numeric`, see [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Numeric.html). And I know I can do this:

```
foo = unreliable
foo && foo > 10
```

But is there a way to use the safe navigation operator with a numeric and `:>`, `:<`, `:==`, `:+`, `:-`, `:/`, `:*`, etc?

---

**Edit**: The focus on `Numeric` in my question is a red herring. See @Jörg's answer. I was confusing Rails's `try` syntax with the safe-navigation operator's syntax.

Comment: Aha, okay—sorry about that. I was trying to express gratitude and let folks know that the answer solved my problem, but I see what you're saying and will do that going forward.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The answer here is perfectly fine. Stop trying to police things that are best left alone.

Comment: @Fuser97381, did I say the answer was wanting? It's an excellent answer.  I would have offered the same advice had it been my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine in Ruby 2.3+ :

```
unreliable&.> 10
```

For example :

```
[-5, 0, nil, 5].each do |unreliable|
  p unreliable&.> 0
end
# false
# false
# nil
# true
```

The way you tried it, Ruby expects `unreliable` to be a callable object such as a `Proc` :

```
unreliable = Proc.new{ |*params| puts "unreliable has been called with #{params}" }
unreliable&.(:>, 10)
# unreliable has been called with [:>, 10]
unreliable.call(:>, 10)
# unreliable has been called with [:>, 10]
unreliable&.call(:>, 10)
# unreliable has been called with [:>, 10]
unreliable[:>, 10]
# unreliable has been called with [:>, 10]
```

With the safe-navigation operator, there's no need to put parens and the method should be a method name, not a symbol (Rails' [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) expects a symbol).

Comment: For the record, `p unreliable&.send( :>,  0)` also works.  Very minor, but I would be inclined to write your operative line `p unreliable&.> 0` because the presence of the period suggests you are not using syntactic sugar.

Comment: @CarySwoveland So without a space between `&.` and `>`? I'm open to suggestions since I couldn't find any pleasant way to format the line.

Comment: That's my tilt. You could of course write `p unreliable&.>(0)` but I'd only consider that if you had something else following on the line (`p unreliable&.>(0) && ...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks. I generally find the safe-nav operator unpleasant to write and read. :-/

Comment: Me too, but maybe we'll feel differently when we've used it more.

Comment: Readers: Eric originally had `unreliable&. > 10`, which was fine. I mention this only to point out that the space after the period is optional.

Comment: I realize where my miscue came from: I was going by analogy to the Rails method `try`, which takes the kinds of parameters I was trying to use. I assume the clunkier Rails syntax reflects that implementing something like the safe-navigation operator requires access to the guts of the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect this has to do with the quirks of allowing only one instance to exist for each `Numeric`

No, this has nothing to do with that at all.

```
foo.(bar)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
foo.call(bar)
```

Ergo,

```
foo&.(bar)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
foo&.call(bar)
```

So, your code:

> ```
> unreliable&.(:>, 10)
> ```

is syntactic sugar for

```
unreliable&.call(:>, 10)
```

I'm not sure who told you that the safe-navigation operator takes the message as a symbol argument. The whole point of the safe-navigation operator is that you only have trivial syntactic overhead by adding a single character, the `&` in front of the `.`, and the expression is otherwise unchanged.

So,

> ```
> unreliable > 10
> ```

which is the same as

```
unreliable.>(10)
```

simply becomes

```
unreliable&.>(10)
```